# Active model serializer nested association nil issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I've the following associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :book 
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
end
```

And my serializers look like:

user_serializer.rb

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ...
  has_one :book, serializer: BookSerializer  
end
```

book_serializer.rb

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ...
  has_many :pages
end
```

Now, when I try to serialize a user object which has no book, it raises an error saying `undefined method pages for nil class`. How can I add a condition that allow serializing book only if it is not nil?

Answer (score 0):

you can decorate your association with something like:

```
has_one :book, serializer: BookSerializer  

def book
   if object.book
     BookSerializer.new(object.book)    
   end
end
```

That's it let me know if that's not what you're looking for